# How to retrieve time in hh:mm:ss format from Time stamp in Java

Tags: java, localdate, dateformatter, localdatetime

I have an issue related to retrieving time from time stamp. Below is the code, I get the timestamp from gui, which I need to convert into hh:mm:ss and insert into database.

```
LocalDate timestamp = LocalDate.parse(getOfferingLetter().getCreatedTimeStamp(),DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"));
Timestamp.valueOf(timestamp.atStartOfDay();
```

The above code retrieves date like this `2022-04-08 00:00:00.0`. I need the time to be retrieved like this `00:00:00`, how do I do this without using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: How about the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`?

Comment: i need only the time to be retrieved in the format "hh:mm:ss" cause thats the format which is accepted by the DB .

Comment: Change the pattern in the `DateTimeFormatter` you are using and must do the work.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev, I already tried and it dint work .

Comment: @Shark, I tried SimpleDateFormat and it returned a string , I again converted it to java.sql.Time and tried inserting and I get DataType Mismatch error which is weird , I tried inserting directly with the values formed in the query in java code and they are inserted fine . Not sure why I am unable to insert with Java code.

Comment: Are you saying that you are receiving a `Timestamp` (an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp`) and you need to get the time of day from it? And you can’t just set it to `00:00:00` every time?

Comment: Isn’t it as simple as `timestampFromGui.toLocalDateTime().toLocalTime()`? It may entail a time zone issue, but if you can’t avoid using `Timestamp`, then there’s no safe way to handle time zone.

Comment: @Shark The question explicitly and wisely said *wihthout using SimpleDateFormat*. The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated, so I believe you can do everyone a favour by ***not*** suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will give you the time:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2000-10-10 10:15:33.123456", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"));
String timeHHmmss = localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeHHmmss);
```

But you cannot create Timestamp from LocalTime.